# np.float not matching both np.float32 and np.float64

Tags: python, numpy, stumpy

I am looking for a way to check if a numpy array is `np.float64` or `np.float32`. This works fine for `np.float64`:

```
a = np.random.rand(10)

if not issubclass(a.dtype.type, np.float):
    raise "Wrong type"  # No exception is raised for np.float64
```

But fails for `np.float32`:

```
a = np.random.rand(10).astype(np.float32)

if not issubclass(a.dtype.type, np.float):
    raise "Wrong type"  # An exception is raised!
```

Comment: Would `a.dtype.type in (np.float32, np.float64)` work?

Comment: Yes, it would work and that was what we were planning to do but it seemed strange that `np.float32` and `np.float64` weren't both subclassed from `np.float`. We were going to go with `if not issubclass(a.dtype.type, (np.float32, np.float64, np.float)):` but this seems verbose

Comment: Well, on a 64 bit system the system type `float` is 64-bit so it kind of makes sense why numpy would not treat a 32 bit float as a subtype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way you can check if a data type is a float is with `issubdtype`:

```
In [1]: a = np.random.rand(10).astype(np.float64)

In [2]: b = np.random.rand(10).astype(np.float32)

In [3]: np.issubdtype(a.dtype,np.floating)
Out[3]: True

In [4]: np.issubdtype(b.dtype,np.floating)
Out[4]: True
```

Comment: I am getting: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.

Comment: Doesn't give me a warning with numpy version `1.13.3`. What version are you using?

Comment: I also tested with version `1.17.0` and it works without warning. Are you sure you used `np.floating` and not `np.float`?